# JSLint "eval is evil." alternatives

Tags: javascript, eval, dry, jslint

I am have some JavaScript functions that run on both the client (browser) and the server (within a Java Rhino context).  These are small functions - basically little validators that are well defined and don't rely upon globals or closures - self-contained and portable.

Here's an example:

```
function validPhoneFormat(fullObject, value, params, property) {
    var phonePattern = /^\+?([0-9\- \(\)])*$/;
    if (value && value.length && !phonePattern.test(value))
        return [ {"policyRequirement": "VALID_PHONE_FORMAT"}];
    else
        return [];
}
```

To keep things DRY, my server code gets a handle on each of these functions and calls toString() on them, returning them to the browser as part of a JSON object.  Something like this:

```
      { "name" : "phoneNumber",
        "policies" : [ 
            { "policyFunction" : "\nfunction validPhoneFormat(fullObject, value, params, property) {\n    var phonePattern = /^\\+?([0-9\\- \\(\\)])*$/;\n    if (value && value.length && !phonePattern.test(value)) {\n        return [{\"policyRequirement\":\"VALID_PHONE_FORMAT\"}];\n    } else {\n        return [];\n    }\n}\n"
            }
          ]
      }
```

My browser JS code then takes this response and creates an instance of this function in that context, like so:

```
eval("var policyFunction = " + this.policies[j].policyFunction);

policyFailures = policyFunction.call(this, form2js(this.input.closest("form")[0]), this.input.val(), params, this.property.name));
```

This all works very well.  However, I then run this code through JSLint, and I get back this message:

*[ERROR] ValidatorsManager.js:142:37:eval is evil.*

I appreciate that often, eval can be dangerous. However, I have no idea how else I could implement such a mechanism without using it. Is there any way I can do this and also pass through the JSLint validator?

Comment: It may just be my lack of experience with such a set-up, but can't you just use the same source in two places?

Comment: @Jasper sadly, no - the system isn't setup to really allow me to read the source files directly from both environments.

Comment: Well, I'd either look into the possibility of changing the setup so that you can, or just deploying the same file in two places (even a link from one to the other could work)

Comment: It sounds like your "system" kinda sucks... :(

Comment: Just include the code below in your file and everything will be well.
/*jshint -W061 */

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it since you are only passing these function strings from the server to the client, and are thus in control of what will be evaluated.

On the other hand, if you were going the other direction and doing the evals of client-passed code on the server, that would be an entirely different story...

**Update:**

As disabling the validation option in your comment may cause you to miss future errors, I would instead suggest passing the function name rather than the entire function and have the function library mirrored on the server and client.  Thus, to call the function, you'd use the following code:

```
var policyFunction = YourLibraryName[this.policies[j].policyFunctionName];
var policyArguments = this.policies[j].policyArguments;

policyFunction.apply(this, policyArguments);
```

**Update 2:**

I was able to validate the following code with JSLint successfully, which essentially allows you to "turn off" validation for the vast minority of cases where `eval` is appropriate.  At the same time, JSLint still validates normal `eval` calls, and all uses of this method should throw up flags for future developers to avoid using it/refactor it out where possible/as time allows.

```
var EVAL_IS_BAD__AVOID_THIS = eval;
EVAL_IS_BAD__AVOID_THIS(<yourString>);
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have JSLint validation as part of our build process.  This means I can't just ignore it - I would have to disable the check.  Although I'm willing to argue for that if necessary, I'd like to check my alternatives first.

Comment: @JakeFeasel:  I'd avoid doing that unless you can ignore it only for that case.  If so, great!  Otherwise, I've added an alternative solution where you pass the entire function library upfront to the client, and only the function name in your JSON object.

Comment: Unfortunately separating out the function definitions in a way that could make them directly accessible to the browser is a fairly large task, and beyond the scope of what I'd like to tackle at this point.

Comment: @JakeFeasel:  Does this code pass JSLint validation:  `var EVAL_IS_BAD = eval;  EVAL_IS_BAD(<yourString>);`?  If so, you'll be darn sure to be careful when using that method, but it still passes validation.

Comment: Haha! Genius! Evil genius perhaps, but genius regardless!  I love it!m You should make that your answer, and I'll accept it. Muhahaha

Comment: @JakeFeasel `eval` is evil enough. `eval` obfuscated to not look like `eval` will surely bring about the apocalypse.

Answer (score 5):

Dont encode a function as a string in JSON. JSON is for content, which you are confounding with behavior.

Instead, I suppose you could return JS files instead, which allow *real* functions:

```
 { name : "phoneNumber",
    policies : [ 
        { policyFunction : function() {
              whateverYouNeed('here');
          }
        }
      ]
  }
```

But while that solves the technical issue, it's still not a great idea.

---

The *real solution* here is to move your logic out of your content entirely. Import a JS file full of little validation functions and call them as needed based on a `dataType` property in your JSON or something. If this functions are as small and portable as you say, this should be trivial to accomplish.

Getting your data all tangled up with your code usually leads to pain. You should statically include your JS, then dynamically request/import/query for your JSON data to run through your statically included code.

Comment: While I agree with what you're saying, the changes necessary to support this would be far beyond what I'm willing to do at this point.

Comment: JSLint is not giving you that warning so that you can find a pedantic work around. It's telling you that you are doing it wrong. And if you care enough about code quality to use JSLint in your build process, then you should care enough to do it right. :(

Comment: Calling it "wrong" is pretty definitive. I see that Douglas Crockford  feels that way, but I wonder - how is what I'm doing here that much different than attaching a new script node to the DOM in order to get a handle on a function that is embedded with a JS object (which is how I interpret your first suggestion)? The function is defined on the server, returned, then interpreted on the browser in both cases (within a larger data structure). I see that you don't much like this first answer, but it does seem pretty similar to what I'm doing, conceptually.

Comment: Well you can't have it both ways. You either care about what JSLint says or you don't. In this case it's pointing out a flaw in your approach of this whole thing. And if you figure out a way to obfuscate your eval so JSLint doesn't complain, you probably havent improved your code. You've actually made it worse.  Either do it right, or don't require that you use a tool to check if you've done it right. But if you want to "fix" the issue JSLint is yelling about, you are going to have to fix your overall approach. Or you can decide JSLint is a whiny bastard and ignore it. But you cant do both.

Comment: Just keep this word of warning in mind from Mozilla's Developer Network: If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.  (ie, your site can be used for phishing attacks).  Good luck.

Comment: 'JSLint is not giving you that warning so that you can find a pedantic work around. It's telling you that you are doing it wrong.' . . And it's often wrong. JSHint is very opiniated (can't use `"` to enclose string for example) and saying that not doing it the JSHint way means you are doing it the wrong way is a very strong statement. Furthermore, saying that `eval` is evil is, imho, short sighted. Yes, `eval` is inappropriate in many scenario's, but there are some things that can only be done by eval. Dynamically creating a named function is one example.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using eval in all situations.  There's no reason you can't code around it.  Instead of sending code to the client, just keep it hosted on the server in one contained script file.

If that's not doable, you can also have a dynamically generated javascript file then pass in the necessary parameters via the response, and then dynamically load the script on the client side.  There's really no reason to use eval.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please create a function with it's name based on a string variable such that you can later see that function name in a debugger. I'm currently see no other way than: `eval('function ' + functionName + '(){}');`. Please show me how to 'code around' eval in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
setInterval("code to be evaluated", 0);
```

Internally, if you pass setInterval a string it performs a function similar to eval().

However, I wouldn't worry about it.  If you KNOW eval() is evil, and take appropriate precautions, it's not really a problem.  Eval is similar to GoTo; you just have to be careful and aware of what you're doing to use them properly.

Comment: `setInterval()` with quotes around the first argument is basically the same as `eval()`

Comment: Also - setInterval() runs asynchronously, doesn't it?  If so, it would require some serious code restructuring to shoehorn the currently-synchronous process into an asynchronous one.  That being said - I'll check it out!

Comment: Well, I can say this much - setTimeout doesn't cause a JSLint error! So far so good.

Comment: That doesn't mean its a good idea. I'd be surprised if JSLint was ok with a string passed to setTimeout by default.

Comment: @AlexWayne It in fact does pass JSLint, although I agree it's certainly not a great idea.  The problems introduced by running it in a separate thread make this particularly unappealing.

Comment: There are no separate threads in Javascript, it's single-threaded. There are WebWorkers, which are sort of threads. `setInterval` just returns before the code is actually executed. But when it eventually does get executed, it gets executed on the same thread that `setInterval` was called in.

Answer (score 1):

With very little parsing you could have had it like so:

```
var body = this.policies[j].policyFunction.substr;
body = body.substr(body.indexOf("(") + 1);
var arglist = body.substr(1, body.indexOf(")"));
body = body.substr(arglist.length + 1);
var policyFunction = new Function(arglist, body);
```

Which would provide a bit of validation, avoid the literal use of `eval` and work synchronously with the code. But it is surely `eval` in disguise, and it is prone to XSS attack. If the malevolent person can get their code loaded and evaluated this way - it will not save you. So, really, just don't do it. Add a `<script>` tag with the proper URL and that would be certainly safer. Well, you know, better safe then sorry.

PS. My apologises if the code above doesn't work, it only shows the intent, I've not tested it, and if I made a mistake at counting parenthesis or some such - well, you should get the idea, I'm not advertising it by any means.

Comment: If the attacker can intercept the Ajax call that loads the JSON to inject his attack code, why wouldn't he be able to intercept the script's source url just as easily? I really don't see how script tags are safer. `eval` is much like SQL queries. Be very careful with inserting content from sources that are beyond your control. If you have full control over the input, than it's essentially safe.

Answer (score 1):

DRY is definitely something I agree with, however there is a point where copy+pasting is more efficient and easy to maintain than referencing the same piece of code.

The code you're saving yourself from writing seems to be equivalent to a clean interface, and simple boiler plate. If the same code is being used on both the server and the client, you could simply pass around the common pieces of the function, rather than the whole function.

```
Payload:
{
    "name": "phoneNumber",
    "type": "regexCheck",
    "checkData": "/^\\+?([0-9\\- \\(\\)])*$/"
}
```

```
if(payload.type === "regexCheck"){
    const result = validPhoneFormat(fullObject, value, payload.checkData)
}

function validPhoneFormat(fullObject, value, regexPattern) {

    if (value && value.length && !regexPattern.test(value))
        return [ {"policyRequirement": "VALID_PHONE_FORMAT"}];
    else
        return [];
}
```

This would give you the ability to update the regex from a single location. If the interface changes it does need to be updated in 2 places, but I wouldn't consider that a bad thing. If the client is running code, why hide the structure?

If you really, really want to keep both the object structure and the patterns in one place - extract it to a single API. Have a "ValidatePhoneViaRegex" api endpoint which is called by all places you'd be passing this serialized function to.

If all of this seems like too much effort, set jslint to ignore your piece of code:

"In JSHint 1.0.0 and above you have the ability to ignore any warning with a special option syntax. The identifier of this warning is W061. This means you can tell JSHint to not issue this warning with the /*jshint -W061 */ directive.

In ESLint the rule that generates this warning is named no-eval. You can disable it by setting it to 0, or enable it by setting it to 1."

https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/eval.md

I would prefer to see copy+pasted code, a common api, or receiving parameters and copy+pasted boiler plate than magical functions passed in from the server to be executed.

What happens if you get a cross-browser compatibility error with one of these shared functions?

Comment: In a modern JS app the there's no "magic", the same code would be assembled into both the client and server side bundle. And there's no danger of cross-browser problems with the type of code originally referred to seven years ago.

Comment: The original question didn't seem to mention the shared json code was a bundle. If it was bundled, I'd expect the code to be a library - not a jsonified library. If the function is passed in during runtime via an API, without debugging the code, it wouldn't be easy to know what the function is doing and what the function relies on without having prior knowledge to every function being passed in. Jsonified code is more obscure than libraries/copy+pasting/APIs. Debugging jsonified code would also be pretty tricky.

Comment: The original question is from seven years ago and we didn't have the options then we do now. No clue what you're saying by "jsonified code", I certainly didn't say anything about it. My point was that cutting and pasting code is almost never good, and makes keeping things in sync more difficult. Shared code these days is trivial because it can be bundled into either client or server side with ease, and recommending code duplication makes zero sense to me.

Comment: The question's second code snippet is a JSONified bit of code. The question is why is calling eval on that JSONified code "evil". My recommendations are around avoiding JSONified code. From my perspective copy+pasting would be a better alternative to sharing code via JSON objects. Libraries and API endpoints performing the function would likely be better still.

Comment: My recommendation is to bundle the same module instead of cutting and pasting code. You're responding to a seven-year old question from the viewpoint of today, where cutting and pasting is unnecessary and error-prone.

Comment: I agree for the most part, however copy+pasting isn't always a bad thing. If the code is being used for the exact same purpose, then yes copy+pasting is likely going to cause pain down the road. If the code is coincidentally doing the same thing now for two different reasons, then copy+pasting may not be a bad thing. For a phone number validation field, maybe international numbers are required on one screen, and local phone numbers without a country code are required on another screen. The regex in the example may be coincidentally the same now, but may want to differ later on etc.

Comment: ... If you're running validation on the client and server, which you must do, the validation will almost always be the same, at least on the textual input. Having *different* text validation on the client and server would be... odd. You could do *additional* validation on one side or both, but... And if different screens require different validation then you'd obviously have multiple validations. I don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to bear in mind is that jsLint does make the point that "it will hurt your feelings". It's designed to point out where you're not following best practices -- but code that isn't perfect can still work just fine; there's no compulsion upon you to follow jsLint's advice.

Having said that, eval *is* evil, and in virtually all cases there is always a way around using it.

In this case, you could use a library such as require.js, yepnope.js or some other library that is designed to load a script separately. This would allow you to include the javascript functions you need dynamically but without having to `eval()` them.

There are probably several other solutions as well, but that was the first one that came to my mind.

Hope that helps.